# How do I write in Georgian with PDFLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, languages, font-encodings

I found these packages but no clear instruction on installing them and using them. No mention of whether I need LaTex, LuaTex or XeTex

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/georgian

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel-georgian

What can I do to install it on linux?

Comment: It says "Download GeoTeX http://tex.tsu.ge and install it in local TEX", how do I install it? (by the way I have tried this before posting the question here, I also tried miktex on windows and many other things, so many things that it was pointless mentioning any of them since I don't know which one is the right way)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok I created texmf directory in the home directory and untared the package there and now it gives different error (so I must have done something right) The error message is "Font djgr8a10 at 540 not found"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few options to use Georgian in LaTeX. A simple one is to use a font that supports the Georgian alphabet, such as *DejaVu Serif*, and compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Tested in Ubuntu Linux:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\begin{document}
Some fonts support Georgian: კატები ყველგანაა
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Another possibility is the [`mxedruli/xucuri`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/georgian/mxedruli/mxeddoc.pdf) package, for pdfLaTeX. For this you write the Georgian text using character codes described in the manual. The installation of the package is very straightforward using `tlmgr` or packages from your distribution package manager (such as `apt`).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mxedruli}
\begin{document}
\begin{mxedr}
.gmertsa +semvedre, nutu .kvla damxsnas soplisa+sromasa,\\
cecxls, .cqalsa da mi.casa, haerta tana +sromasa;\\
momcnes prteni da a.gvprinde, mivhxvde mas +cemsandomasa,\\
d.gisit da .gamit vhxedvide mzisa elvata .krtomasa.
\end{mxedr}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

The packages that you found are also useful, but more difficult to install - so maybe one of these two options are sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Finally! The first suggestion worked. Command one needs to run is `lualatex file.tex`

Comment: @AlexandreGurchumelia good that it worked. You can also use `xelatex file.tex` (both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX support system fonts with `fontspec`).

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is good, but doesn’t say how to install this package.

First, if you can possibly run LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, and use Unicode fonts instead, you should.  It’s much simpler and works much better.  Otherwise, read on.

If your distro has packages that install these files for you, you should use those.  On Debian or Ubuntu, you can look for an OS package with `apt-file`.

If you run MikTeX, you can use its installer to install both `georgian` and `babel-georgian`.  If you run TeX Live, which is what most Linux distros use, you might be able to install `babel-georgian` through `tlmgr`, although Debian-based distributions disable this and make you manually install that too.

There is neither a TeX Live, Debian nor Ubuntu package containing the `georgian` files on CTAN (as of 2019).  To install that, [download the package contents from CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/georgian) and unpack them under your `$TEXMFLOCAL` directory (typically `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-local/`).  See [the installation notes.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/georgian/doc/latex/georgian/geotex-en.pdf)

Whenever you manually install packages to the local texmf directory, you must run `texhash` and `updmap-sys --enable Map=mapfile.map`.

You could instead try installing to your home directory, under `~/texmf`, but I do not recommend that: You would need to run `updmap` to create a font map under your home directory, which will break any updates to your system font map.

Comment: If you are using a linux distro Texlive, you should use your distro's package manager to install `babel-georgian` rather than installing it manually. It is better to use a local config than run `updmap-sys` with `--enable`, but I don't know how this works on Debian systems. Funny `georgian` isn't in Texlive.

Comment: @cfr Agreed. Unfortunately, when I searched for the files in `babel-georgian`, I didn’t find a Debian package for it. I might've missed it, though. Would appreciate a link if someone does have one.

Comment: @cfr Good suggestion to mention that people should look for a distro package. Added instructions for that.

Comment: @Davislor unfortunately I'm using Debian.

Comment: @AlexandreGurchumelia Okay. You can install `babel-georgian` by the same method as `georgian`.